# A word for someone who can notice things quickly?

Tags: single-word-requests

Other than words like 'insightful', 'observant', and 'perceptive', is there another word?

Comment: How about 'alert'? 'Responsive'?

Comment: Please tell us a little bit more about how you want to use this word. Can you give an example of how you would use it in a sentence? Do you want an adjective, like the words you listed? Why aren't you satisfied with those three words? What other words did you find when you looked in a thesaurus to see synonyms of these words?

Comment: Colloquially, idiomatically - *quick on the uptake*!  Or does that refer to someone who learns quickly?

Comment: "discerning" or "acute" would be my choices, depending on context. Quite a few scientific publications use "rapid discernment" as synonymous with "quick detection".

Answer (score 9):

***sharp-eyed***

> : having a strong ability to notice things [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sharpeyed)

***sharp-sighted***

> : keenly perceptive or alert; "quick-sighted into the faults of the time"- Leonard Bacon : also, **quick-sighted**, **sharp-eyed** [WordNet](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sharp-sighted)

Answer (score 6):

Someone who notices things quickly could be called *perspicacious*.

**Definition**: having a ready insight into and understanding of things: it offers quite a few facts to the perspicacious reporter.

**Derivatives**:
perspicaciously adverb
Origin early 17th cent.: from Latin perspicax, perspicac- ‘seeing clearly’ + -acious .

**synonyms**:   discerning, shrewd, perceptive, astute, penetrating, observant, percipient, sharp-witted, sharp, smart, alert, clear-sighted, farsighted, acute, clever, canny, intelligent, insightful, wise, sage, sensitive, intuitive, understanding, aware, discriminating.

**antonyms**:   stupid

Comment: This post would be improved by explaining *why* you suggest this term, for example, by providing a dictionary definition or examples in the wild. I encourage you take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Comment: This is the answer, IMO.

Comment: @Drew why not upvote this one if that is the case?

Comment: @Morpheus: I already had. Why do you ask?

Comment: @Drew Sorry, I guess I didn't realize there was such a long lag before others could see it.

Comment: @Morpheus: No problem.

Answer (score 3):

Consider **keen-eyed** or **keen-sighted**. Another word is **eagle-eyed**:

> very good at seeing or noticing things

([Longman](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/eagle-eyed))

If a short idiom is OK, try **"a keen eye for something"**:

> an ability to notice and recognize something

(Macmillan English Dictionary)

Example: *My dad has a keen eye for talent.*

Answer (score 1):

If you mean literally *see* things quickly, then Elian's quite right about *sharp-eyed*.

If you mean *perceive* things quickly, particularly abstract concepts, *quick* itself is frequently used as an adjective:

> ***quick***
>
> adjective
>
> 3. fast in learning or understanding [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quick)

Examples:

*she's very quick*

*he has a quick mind*

Answer (score 0):

[On the ball](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/on+the+ball)

Definition:

> 1. Alert, competent, or efficient; active and aware of things:

Examples:

> A teacher who is really on the ball.
>
> FBI agents were very much on the ball in the Bremer snatch.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on the usage - "intuition" or "intuitiveness"

Example:
His intuition was uncanny...

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, even if it's correct. Please **define** the difference -- because both your words are nouns, they both fit in the sentence. What is the usage needed for each word?